# Extract data from Individual Oracle SQL Queries into individual excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am very new to VBA code and macros and I would like to learn or need help with writing a VBA macro for running individual oracle SQL Queries in to individual excel sheets.

I need to run 6 similar queries and extract data from those 6 queries into 6 different excel sheets in a single excel workbook. The column referral type in the query will be hardcoded differently for those 6 queries.

For eg. I have pasted an oracle SQL query(1 out of 6) for referral type category 1:

```
SELECT * from dumm@addresstable WHERE TRIM(UPPER(A.REFERRAL_TYPE)) = 'MARKETING_ALLAINCE'
```

I have this VBA Code, but i do not know how to include 6 queries in here?

```
Sub GetData()
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sqlText As String
Dim Row As Long
Dim Findex As Long
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim X As Long
  Set Data = Sheets("Results")
  Data.Select
  Cells.ClearContents
  Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=DATABASE;USER 
  ID=User1;PASSWORD=Pwd1" 
  Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS"
Cmd.CommandText = sqlText
Set RS = Cmd.Execute
For X = 1 To RS.Fields.Count
    Data.Cells(1, X) = RS.Fields(X - 1).Name
Next

If RS.RecordCount < Rows.Count Then
    Data.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS
Else
    Do While Not RS.EOF
       Row = Row + 1
       For Findex = 0 To RS.Fields.Count - 1
         If Row >= Rows.Count - 50 Then
            Exit For
         End If
         Data.Cells(Row + 1, Findex + 1) = RS.Fields(Findex).Value
       Next Findex
       RS.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

If i am able to get help with this VBA code, I would be able to automate the task and it will really help me deliver on time and provide daily reporting.

Comment: Plenty of examples out there - eg see http://www.jtrive.com/pages/about-me.html

Comment: I am unable to paste the code.

Comment: Update your sub to something like `GetData(SQL As String, rngDest As Range)` then you can call it like (eg) `GetData "select * from table1", Sheets("Results").Range("A1")`